# remove added inputs per button click

Tags: javascript

Add input per button click

```
function addInput() {
        counter++;
        // Create form inline div for product id
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute('class', 'form-inline');
        div.id = 'form-inline'+counter;
        // Create column div for product id
        const div1 = document.createElement("div");
        div1.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-3');
        // Create form group div for product id
        const div2 = document.createElement("div");
        div2.setAttribute('class', 'form-group');
        // Create label of Item ID for product id
        const label = document.createElement("label");
        label.htmlFor = 'ItemID' + counter;
        label.innerHTML = "Item ID " + counter;
        // Create input of Item ID for product id
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.id = 'ItemID' + counter;
        input.type = 'text';
        input.name = 'ItemID' + counter;
        input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
        input.placeholder = 'Enter product id';
        // Create column div for product count
        const div4 = document.createElement("div");
        div4.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-3');
        div4.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:10%;');
        // Create form group div for product count
        const div5 = document.createElement("div");
        div5.setAttribute('class', 'form-group');
        // Create label of Item Count for product id
        const label2 = document.createElement("label");
        label2.htmlFor = 'ItemCount' + counter;
        label2.innerHTML = "Item Count " + counter;
        // Create input of Item Count for product id
        const input2 = document.createElement("input");
        input2.id = 'ItemCount' + counter;
        input2.type = 'text';
        input2.name = 'ItemCount' + counter;
        input2.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
        input2.placeholder = 'Enter product count';
        // Append all items/divs
        form.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(div1);
        div1.appendChild(div2);
        div2.appendChild(label);
        div2.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(div4);
        div4.appendChild(div5);
        div5.appendChild(label2);
        div5.appendChild(input2);
      }
```

Remove input per button click

```
function removeInput() {
        if (counter > 0) {
          //document.getElementById("form-inline"+counter).remove();
          //document.getElementById("form-inline"+counter).remove();
          //document.getElementById("form-inline"+counter).removeChild(document.getElementById("form-inline"+counter).lastChild);
        } else {
          alert("error");
        }
      }
```

I basically want to be able to add as many inputs, and if needed to remove a couple, to remove them. at the end of the day you should be able to remove inputs until there are none left. The problem I'm having here is that the counter stops at the last added input and sets it to the last number so It will only remove the last input and I can't figure out how to go deeper than that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. "*I basically want...*" isn't a question. Please review [ask] and edit your question to identify a clear question while including only the code necessary to reproduce the issue you're encountering with your attempt as a [mre].

Comment: `counter--;` after you've removed an input, maybe? (P.S. Doesn't seem to be anything to do with PHP, I've removed that tag for you.)

Comment: Here's one way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/w5sqz34r/

Comment: thats just how I talk, I know what I want and I feel like I explained what I'm trying to do. Also, thanks for those who responded I appreciate it.